# Whoosh IndexingError: Writer is closed

Tags: python, whoosh

I am using the code, and I am getting as error message

> This writer is closed

I am using whoosh and python. I am fetching data from a json file and I then iterate with a loop for creating the search engine index.

```py
from whoosh.fields import Schema,TEXT,ID
from whoosh import index
from whoosh.qparser import QueryParser
import os.path
import json
if not os.path.exists("indexdir"):
  os.mkdir("indexdir")
  schema = Schema(title=TEXT(stored=True), content=TEXT(stored=True))
  ix = index.create_in("indexdir", schema)
  doc_json=json.load(open("review.json",'r'))
  for doc in doc_json:
     with ix.writer() as w:
        for key,value in doc.get('properties').items():
           w.add_document(title=str(key), content=str(value[0].get('value')))
           w.commit()
```

Comment: Please post the actual error.

Comment: File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/whoosh/filedb/filewriting.py", line 179, in     _check_state
    raise IndexingError("This writer is closed")
whoosh.writing.IndexingError: This writer is closed

Comment: Welcome to SO! I tried to improve your question. For further reference: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @PrakherAgarwal Post the error in your question not the comments.

Answer (score 0):

w.commit() closes the writer, so you can do it like this:

```
with ix.writer() as w:
    for doc in doc_json:
        for key,value in doc.get('properties').items():
            w.add_document(title=str(key), content=str(value[0].get('value')))
    w.commit()
```